# List of European countries and capitals with populations

Tags: data-request, json, europe

I am searching a list of European countries and capitals with populations. This list must include the name of country with its population and area in square kilometer, the capital of country with its population. I want get this data in format of JSON document like

```
{
    "countryName": "Belgium",
    "countryPopulation": "11258000",
    "area": "30510.0",
    "countryCapital": "Brussels",
    "capitalPopulation": "107307"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A source of data in JSON would be a port of the [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/).

[Github repo](https://github.com/openmundi/factbook.json)

For example, the entry for Belgium

```
https://github.com/openmundi/factbook.json/blob/master/europe/be-belgium.json
```

Has dictionary entries:

```
  "major_urban_areas_population": {
  "text": "BRUSSELS (capital) 1.892 million; Antwerp 961,000 (2009)"}
```

and

```
"area": {
  "total": "30,528 sq km",
  "land": "30,278 sq km",
  "water": "250 sq km"
},
```

and

```
"population": {
  "text": "10,444,268 (July 2013 est.)"
},
```

to select a few.

There are other ports of the CIA World Factbook that may better structure that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Countries](https://mledoze.github.io/countries/) repo on Github, which includes all the fields you want except population. You'll have to filter on `"region":"Europe"`

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mledoze/countries/master/dist/countries.json
```

Example for Belgium entry:

```
{
   "name":{
      "common":"Belgium",
      "official":"Kingdom of Belgium",
      "native":{
         "deu":{
            "official":"K\u00f6nigreich Belgien",
            "common":"Belgien"
         },
         "fra":{
            "official":"Royaume de Belgique",
            "common":"Belgique"
         },
         "nld":{
            "official":"Koninkrijk Belgi\u00eb",
            "common":"Belgi\u00eb"
         }
      }
   },
   "tld":[
      ".be"
   ],
   "cca2":"BE",
   "ccn3":"056",
   "cca3":"BEL",
   "cioc":"BEL",
   "currency":[
      "EUR"
   ],
   "callingCode":[
      "32"
   ],
   "capital":"Brussels",
   "altSpellings":[
      "BE",
      "Belgi\u00eb",
      "Belgie",
      "Belgien",
      "Belgique",
      "Kingdom of Belgium",
      "Koninkrijk Belgi\u00eb",
      "Royaume de Belgique",
      "K\u00f6nigreich Belgien"
   ],
   "region":"Europe",
   "subregion":"Western Europe",
   "languages":{
      "deu":"German",
      "fra":"French",
      "nld":"Dutch"
   },
   "translations":{
      "cym":{
         "official":"Kingdom of Belgium",
         "common":"Gwlad Belg"
      },
      "deu":{
         "official":"K\u00f6nigreich Belgien",
         "common":"Belgien"
      },
      "fra":{
         "official":"Royaume de Belgique",
         "common":"Belgique"
      },
      "hrv":{
         "official":"Kraljevina Belgija",
         "common":"Belgija"
      },
      "ita":{
         "official":"Regno del Belgio",
         "common":"Belgio"
      },
      "jpn":{
         "official":"\u30d9\u30eb\u30ae\u30fc\u738b\u56fd",
         "common":"\u30d9\u30eb\u30ae\u30fc"
      },
      "nld":{
         "official":"Koninkrijk Belgi\u00eb",
         "common":"Belgi\u00eb"
      },
      "por":{
         "official":"Reino da B\u00e9lgica",
         "common":"B\u00e9lgica"
      },
      "rus":{
         "official":"\u041a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e \u0411\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0433\u0438\u044f",
         "common":"\u0411\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0433\u0438\u044f"
      },
      "spa":{
         "official":"Reino de B\u00e9lgica",
         "common":"B\u00e9lgica"
      },
      "fin":{
         "official":"Belgian kuningaskunta",
         "common":"Belgia"
      }
   },
   "latlng":[
      50.83333333,
      4
   ],
   "demonym":"Belgian",
   "landlocked":false,
   "borders":[
      "FRA",
      "DEU",
      "LUX",
      "NLD"
   ],
   "area":30528
}
```

They don't include population, because

> restrain from sending too detailed, regional or changing countries data like financial or economic data (e.g. GDP, population, etc.)

(link to [CONTRIBUTING.MD](https://github.com/mledoze/countries/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md))

Comment: Thanks, but I looking data with population. I don't need update of population(2015). It can be 2010. I need get a population of country and capital.